# Заполнение RecyclerView

Tags: android

По непонятной мне причине не получается добавить элемент в RecyclerView.

У меня есть метод `onActivityResult` и в нем я делаю следующие вещи:

```
file.add(new FileModel());
```

В свою очередь, где-то выше в методе OnStart:

```
file = new ArrayList<>();

fAdapter = new ADDFileAdapter(file);
rvAddFile.setAdapter(fAdapter);
```

Если я заполняю `file` в методе `OnStart` элементы добавляются и отображаются.

```
        rvAddFile.setAdapter(fAdapter);
        file.add(new FileModel());
        file.add(new FileModel());
        file.add(new FileModel());
```

Вопрос, почему в методе `onActivityResul`t элементы не добавляются в RecyclerView?

**UPD**

```
public class ADDFileAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ADDFileAdapter.ADDFileViewHolder> {

ArrayList<FileModel> fileConteiner;

public ADDFileAdapter(ArrayList<FileModel> fileConteiner) {
    this.fileConteiner = fileConteiner;
}

@Override
public ADDFileViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.add_file_card_layout, parent, false);
    ADDFileAdapter.ADDFileViewHolder nh = new ADDFileAdapter.ADDFileViewHolder(v);
    return nh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ADDFileViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Context ctx = holder.itemView.getContext();
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lparams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lparamsFile = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(100,100);

    LinearLayout linearLayoutFileContent = new LinearLayout(ctx);     //Контейнер для вложения 
    linearLayoutFileContent.setLayoutParams(lparams);
    for (int i = 0; i < fileConteiner.size(); i++){
        ImageView file = new ImageView(ctx);    //Изображение вложения
        file.setLayoutParams(lparamsFile);
        file.setImageDrawable(ctx.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.audio));
        linearLayoutFileContent.addView(file);
    }
    holder.cv.addView(linearLayoutFileContent);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return fileConteiner.size();
}

public static class ADDFileViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

    CardView cv;

    public ADDFileViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        cv = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.add_file_card);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
    }
}
```

Метод `onActivityResult`

```
if(u.toString().equals("image/jpeg")
                     || u.toString().equals("image/png")
                     || u.toString().equals("image/gif")
                     || u.toString().equals("image/tiff")){

                 fileAdd.add(new FileModel());
                 fAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
             }
```

**Отладчик**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы делаете вызов метода вашадаптер.notifyDataSetChanged?

Comment: Да, увы он не помогает в данной ситуации

Comment: Попробуйте тогда переопределить в адаптере массив значений который должен отображаться. Если и он не поможет тогда .... а вы уверены что onActivityResult у вас вызывается?

Comment: Да, вызывается. Добавил сам адаптер выше

Comment: поставьте перед вызовом notifyDataSetChanged  mADDFileAdapter.fileConteiner = List<Новый список>

Comment: fAdapter = new ADDFileAdapter(file);
        ADDFileAdapter.fileConteiner = new ArrayList<>();
        fAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();   Если я правильно понял, это не помогло

Comment: это вы так в ActivityResult так лихо?  Не надо заново создавать адаптер. Просто заполните там массив. Либо сделайте его public либо создайте для него set-метод. PS в данном коде он будет у вас пустым.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

в `onActivityResult()` после добавления данных:

```
file.add(new FileModel());
```

оповестите адаптер об изменениях, вызовом `notifyDataSetChanged()`:

```
fAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

Если это не сработает, то либо:

- ссылка на адаптер уже не актуальный адаптер;
- адаптер ссылается на другую коллекцию, не ту, в которую вы добавили данные.

**UPD:**

file **!=** fileAdd

т.е. см. пункт №2 выше

Comment: В режиме отладчика проверил коллекцию, она заполняется корректно , ссылка на adapter тоже не теряется

Comment: @Heaven дополните вопрос вашим методом `onActivityResult()`

Comment: Добавил часть метода которые отвечает за добавление элементов. Условие проходит нормально. Упросил даже Adapter, увы не помогает

Comment: @Heaven обновил ответ

Comment: Добавил скрин с отладчика, в Adapter приходит filleAdd который я заполнил в OnActivityResult

Comment: @Heaven вы не поняли, `filleAdd` это другая коллекция, она никак не связана с адаптером, с адаптером у вас связана коллекция `file`

Comment: коллекция file = filleAdd, я её переименовал, думал что возможно где-то идет конфликт имен. то есть сейчас у меня наименование коллекции filleAdd а не file

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52290/discussion-between-heaven-and-ermak0ff).

Answer (score 1):

Перенес инициализацию данных в метод `onCreate`. Видимо когда вызывался `onActivityResult` терялась ссылка на фрагмент, хотя он не уничтожался полностью а переходил в стадию `onStop`

**onStart**

```
public void onStart() {
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        rvAddFile = (RecyclerView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.file_content);
        fLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
        rvAddFile.setLayoutManager(fLayoutManager);
        fAdapter = new ADDFileAdapter(fileAdd);
}
```

**onCreate**

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        fileAdd = new ArrayList<>();

    }
```

и собственно сам **OnActivityResult**

```
fileAdd.add(new FileModel());
rvAddFile.setAdapter(fAdapter);
fAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```